# eCharts resize method not working in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, graph, charts, echarts

i want to refresh/reload the graph each time the window is resized. From the documentation of echarts i understood that this can be achieved by calling the resize() method.

I am trying to call the resize method by this:

```
    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
        onResize(event) {
    this.chartOptions.resize();
  }
```

this.chartOptions is an instance of the chart. it looks something like this :

```
this.chartOptions = {
type:'radar'
indicators: []
series: []
}

etc
```

However each time the window is resized im getting this error:

[image]

Do anyone know why? all the examples i found online are just following what I did.

Comment: You should be calling `resize` method on **chartInstance** not on **chartOptions**

Comment: but i must define the chartInstance variable right?  i added chartInstance:any; and tried to call like this.chartInstance.resize() but is undefined

Comment: You must retrieve it from the library you use for echarts

Comment: im not able ehcarts library cant find it